# AHCI mode with mechanical drive and SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

My home- built system runs Windows7 Pro 32 bit. I bought an SSD and have installed Win 7 Pro 64 bit on it, and plan to use my old mechanical drive for data storage, etc. I set the SATA mode to AHCI before installing Windows on the SSD.

Will there be any problem using the mechanical drive and SSD together, with AHCI mode set?

I needed to boot from the mechanical drive and set the mode back to IDE (after unhooking the SSD). That worked fine of course..

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using SSD and mechanical driver for 3 years together with no problem on windows 7 Pro 64 bit with AHCI mode enabled, so answer is no, there will be no problems.